# How to see what deleted my rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Every night and 8 P.M. something deletes rows in a table. Is there any way to monitor and see which procedure or SQL did that?
The table has ON DELETE triggers, which showed me that the records were deleted last night. I inserted the rows again, but the same thing happened.
Is there any table that stores some SQL History abroad all users?

I tried to find a table that contains history data, but could not.

Comment: Enable **auditing** (if you're a DBA. If not, talk to them).

Comment: You can also query the `dba_source` view for all code that makes use of this table and see if you can find it that way.

Comment: Look at `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS`, `DBA_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES` or `DBA_JOBS` and see if there is a job scheduled to run at 8pm every day.

Answer (score 2):

Auditing or enriched trigger logging is the only way to capture every possible DML. But you may be able to get your answer without it.

Oracle records the wait state of every session once a second and stores that information in ASH (*Active Session History*) in memory, then flushes 1 out of 10 of those samples to a table (on disk) which it keeps for generally several weeks, depending on the configuration. As long as your delete activity took more than 1 second and happened in the past couple hours, or took more than 10 seconds and happened in the past couple weeks, you should be able to locate the activity and see who did it by querying ASH data. Here's how:

For very recent activity:

```
 SELECT sa.sql_id,
           sa.sql_text,
           ash.sample_time,
           ash.inst_id,
           ash.session_id,
           ash.session_serial#,
           u.username,
           ash.module,
           ash.program,
           ash.machine,
           ash.action,
           COUNT(DISTINCT ash.sample_time) secs,
           MIN(ash.sample_time) start_time,
           MAX(ash.sample_time) end_time
      FROM gv$active_session_history ash,
           gv$sqlarea sa,
           dba_users u
     WHERE ash.sql_id = sa.sql_id
       AND ash.inst_id = sa.inst_id
       AND sa.command_type IN (7,189) -- delete or merge (which can also do a delete)
       AND ash.sample_time BETWEEN ((TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1)+17/24) AND ((TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1)+19/24) -- between 7pm and 9pm last night
       AND ash.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY sa.sql_id,
             sa.sql_text,
             ash.sample_time,
             ash.inst_id,
             ash.session_id,
             ash.session_serial#,
             u.username,
             ash.module,
             ash.program,
             ash.machine,
             ash.action
```

If you get results, scan through them and see if you see a statement that would delete rows from the table in question. ASH only keeps info in memory for a short time, so if it's been flushed already you may have to use the historical version:

```
 SELECT sa.sql_id,
           CAST(SUBSTR(sa.sql_text,1,2000) AS varchar2(2000)) sql_text,
           ash.sample_time,
           ash.instance_number,
           ash.session_id,
           ash.session_serial#,
           u.username,
           ash.module,
           ash.program,
           ash.machine,
           ash.action,
           COUNT(DISTINCT ash.sample_time)*10 secs,
           MIN(ash.sample_time) start_time,
           MAX(ash.sample_time) end_time
      FROM dba_hist_active_sess_history ash,
           dba_hist_sqltext sa,
           dba_users u
     WHERE ash.sql_id = sa.sql_id
       AND sa.command_type IN (7,189) -- delete or merge (which can also do a delete)
       AND ash.sample_time BETWEEN ((TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1)+17/24) AND ((TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1)+19/24) -- between 7pm and 9pm last night
       AND ash.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY sa.sql_id,
             CAST(SUBSTR(sa.sql_text,1,2000) AS varchar2(2000)),
             ash.sample_time,
             ash.instance_number,
             ash.session_id,
             ash.session_serial#,
             u.username,
             ash.module,
             ash.program,
             ash.machine,
             ash.action
```